# Error in installing Bad Piggies game through Wine

Tags: wine

I am trying to install Bad piggies game using Wine but the following is appearing in the Terminal:

```
vmlinux@ubuntu:~$ wine uninstaller
fixme:storage:create_storagefile Storage share mode not implemented.
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:richedit:ReadStyleSheet skipping optional destination
err:msi:ACTION_InstallFiles Failed to copy L"C:\\users\\vmlinux\\Application Data\\Rovio Entertainment Ltd\\Bad Piggies 1.3.0.0\\install\\9D1A059\\updater.exe" to L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Rovio Entertainment Ltd.\\Bad Piggies\\updater.exe" (2)
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"InstallFiles" returned 1603
err:msi:ITERATE_Actions Execution halted, action L"ExecuteAction" returned 1603
```

The installation failed. What may the problem be? 
(I have Ubuntu 13.04).Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to install it but only the initial release (version 1.0.0).
According to winehq.org that is.
Instructions to make it work can be found here: http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26748

You are trying to install version 1.3.0.0 which is confirmed to NOT work on wine. You can however use a VM (virtual machine) to get it to work.